# Why allowing comment edits for only 5 minutes?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, locked

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)
>   [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

I have low rep on onstartups.com, and I tried to edit my comment only to get a message box saying something how I can not edit comment within the first 5 minutes (or after 5 minutes, I forgot). Anyway, my comment is locked in.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Comment: @sarnold yes, that answers it. thanks, but why not post as an answer?

Comment: because I'm new enough at meta that I'm unfamiliar with protocols here; I assumed your question would be closed quickly :) but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Better yet: [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes) But indeed, @sarnold, as even the OP agrees it's a duplicate, this will surely be closed. Of course, the OP could still click "delete" too. Either way, posting an answer would not have added much.