# Timeout for Edit Comment

Tags: discussion

Is there any reason regarding performance issue or security to make button `edit` in feature `add comment` has timeout?

I got problem to edit my comment when the button `edit` disappear, so for now what I'm doing is:

1. Copy the comment
2. And then `delete` the comment
3. And then `add` new comment
4. Paste the previous comment and `post`.

**Can the feature `edit on comment` become like `edit on question or answer`?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unlike answers, comments are [semi-]**threaded**. That is to say, other people frequently post comments that refer to or reply to your comment, and those replies will appear *after* your comment.

Preventing you from editing your original comment preserves sanity in these discussions. If you could go back and edit an old comment, you could *completely* change the meaning of the entire conversation.

Consider the following contrived example:

> **The Establishment:** I think this is a *great* feature request!
>   **Crazenezz:** Yes, that's why I posted it.

Later, I go back and make a slight edit to my comment, resulting in this:

> **The Establishment:** I think this is a *stupid and utterly ridiculous* feature request!
>   **Crazenezz:** Yes, that's why I posted it.

The five minute edit window is purely to fix things like typos that you might notice only *after* you clicked "Submit". You shouldn't rely on it even existing.

Comment: Ah I see the reason. Thank you for your explanation. Is it wrong to ask about this thing?

Comment: @Crazenezz: No, not at all. And I don't *actually* think this is stupid or ridiculous. I was just making a point! :-) If you're wondering why it was downvoted, that's probably because [votes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Yeah, read it. So the downvoted means other users didn't agree with my request is it?

Comment: @Crazenezz: I mean, I can only *assume* that's why they are downvoting. That's a pretty common practice on Meta. But people can downvote for any silly reason they want. For all I know, maybe something suggested to them subliminally that you're the epitome of "craziness".

Comment: Hahahahahaha... No problem, just want to think _out of the box_ :-)

Comment: Why is there a link to edit a comment after the grace period?

Comment: now the link doesnt show up

Answer (score 4):

In the SE ecosystem, comments are inherently transient. You can expect them to be deleted at some point as they loose relevancy. If the feedback in a comment is properly taken into account, the thing that will get edited is the question or answer that it is attached to, at which point the comment will be deleted as obsolete.

Not allowing comments to be edited helps re-enforce proper usage of the system. Where this to change, the functional uses of the comment system would change, changing the whole dynamic of focusing on questions and answers. It would also bring baggage such as revision history and stuff that would be a net loss to the clean focused nature of the way things are now.

Please take the lack of an edit feature as a reminder of the transient nature of comments, and use the tool appropriately. If you find that a comment is inaccurate and need to correct it, do exactly what you have been: post a new comment and delete the old one. This will generate a new notice to the owner of the post so they can take your comment into consideration.