# Why can't comments be edited?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

I was adding a comment to a question and had a typo that I didn't notice until it was entered. Comments can be flagged, voted but not edited. Why?

Comment: They can be edited for 5 minutes after they're posted...

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your own comments for up to 5 minutes after adding.

After that, you can always delete them and create a new comment. Comments are not the focus of Stack Exchange sites, the juicy bits here should be in the questions and answers.

Comment: I was using an ipad for this and I didn't see an edit option...

Comment: This was on stackoverflow.

Comment: Tap on the comment, I believe it'll appear then. Normally it appears on a mouse-over. On my iPhone (mobile site) I see the edit links right next to the comment.

Comment: If you are using an iPad, please double-check for site features on a PC before asking for why a feature is missing. :-)

Comment: Could be a rendering issue so I still think it's a valid question

Comment: Not the way it stands now. You didn't see the edit option because you are using a mobile device but your question doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: There is [an edit link on the mobile version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTTc.jpg).

Comment: @animuson: Exactly, saw the same using an iPhone and running Safari with an iPad user agent also works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with your comment, it is possible for you to delete your own comment, and post a new one with the typo corrected.